# If/Else Statements on Arduino not executing

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, programming, arduino-ide, loop

I have a bit of code below, the problem is only the first 'if' statement will execute when called on. When I call on *u, q, or any of the other if statements* it will go straight to the else and not execute. Tried switching the following ifs to 'else if' but got the same result.

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <DHT.h>
#include "DHT.h"

DHT dht1(3, DHT11);
DHT dht2(2, DHT11);

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(12,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(11,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13,LOW);
  digitalWrite(12,LOW);
  digitalWrite(11,LOW);
  digitalWrite(10,LOW);
  digitalWrite(9,LOW);
  digitalWrite(8,LOW);
  digitalWrite(7,LOW);
  digitalWrite(6,LOW);
  digitalWrite(5,LOW);
  digitalWrite(4,LOW);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  dht1.begin();
  dht2.begin();
}

void loop() 
{
  float DHT11_t = dht1.readTemperature(true);
  float DHT21_t = dht2.readTemperature(true);

  if(Serial.read() == 'u')
  {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print(DHT11_t,1);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print(DHT21_t,1);
    Serial.println();
  }

  if(Serial.read() == 'c')
  {
    digitalWrite(13,LOW);
    digitalWrite(12,LOW);
    digitalWrite(11,LOW);
    digitalWrite(10,LOW);
    digitalWrite(9,LOW);
    digitalWrite(8,LOW);
    digitalWrite(7,LOW);
    digitalWrite(6,LOW);
    digitalWrite(5,LOW);
    digitalWrite(4,LOW);
    Serial.print("NDX");
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("u");
    Serial.println();
  }

  if(Serial.read() == 'q')
  {
    digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(11,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
    Serial.print("STX");
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("u");
    delay(2000);
    Serial.print("u");
    delay(2000);
    Serial.print("u");
    delay(2000);
    Serial.print("u");
    delay(2000);
    Serial.print("u");
    delay(2000);
    digitalWrite(13,LOW);
    digitalWrite(12,LOW);
    digitalWrite(11,LOW);
    digitalWrite(10,LOW);
    digitalWrite(9,LOW);
    Serial.print("NDX");
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("u");
    Serial.println();
  }

  if(Serial.read() == 'w')
  {
    digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
  }

  else if(Serial.read() == 'e')
  {
    digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(11,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
  }

  if(Serial.read() == 'r')
  {
    digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
  }

  if(Serial.read() == 't')
  {
    digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(11,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
    delay(30000);
    digitalWrite(13,LOW);
    digitalWrite(12,LOW);
    digitalWrite(11,LOW);
    digitalWrite(10,LOW);
    digitalWrite(9,LOW);
    delay(750);
    digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
    delay(30000);
    digitalWrite(8,LOW);
    digitalWrite(7,LOW);
    digitalWrite(6,LOW);
    digitalWrite(5,LOW);
    digitalWrite(4,LOW);
  }

  if(Serial.read() == 'y')
  {
    digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(11,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
    delay(30000);
    digitalWrite(13,LOW);
    digitalWrite(12,LOW);
    digitalWrite(11,LOW);
    digitalWrite(10,LOW);
    digitalWrite(9,LOW);
    delay(750);
    digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
    delay(30000);
    digitalWrite(8,LOW);
    digitalWrite(7,LOW);
    digitalWrite(6,LOW);
    digitalWrite(5,LOW);
    digitalWrite(4,LOW);
  }

  else
  {
    digitalWrite(13,LOW);
    digitalWrite(12,LOW);
    digitalWrite(11,LOW);
    digitalWrite(10,LOW);
    digitalWrite(9,LOW);
    digitalWrite(8,LOW);
    digitalWrite(7,LOW);
    digitalWrite(6,LOW);
    digitalWrite(5,LOW);
    digitalWrite(4,LOW);
  }

}
```

Comment: We already told you that it is not working: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/56646/simple-timings-in-arduino-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Serial.read()` takes the first byte out of the serial buffer. Once it's executed, this byte is gone, so the `Serial.read()` in the next if statement will fetch the next byte (if available). What you can do is assign the result of `Serial.read()` to some variable before the first if statement, and then use that variable instead of `Serial.read()` in the if statements.

Comment: Can you post the fix? I tried defining the var but got 'not declared in this scope'

Comment: @nuggetchris Please take a look at the example from https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read. It should work if you put your if statements after `incomingByte = Serial.read();` (inside `if (Serial.available() > 0) { }`).

Comment: And this is also switching Serial.read() == x within the if statement with incomingByte == x?

Comment: @nuggetchris: Yes. Sorry, I forgot to mention it.

Comment: Ok, it seems to work as long as I define a data type before incomingByte. Since it's only letters, I went with char. Only problem now is, the serial.printed letters the *program* produces, such as in the 'u' in the if statements, it doesn't seem to recognize. It only prints the 'u' but does not execute what the 'u' is stated to execute in the first if statement

Comment: Technically could insert logic directly in place of the call but if I could streamline it as planned would be much better

Comment: @nuggetchris: I'm not sure why it doesn't recognize characters in the if statements. You are using `==` inside `if()`, right? Try the following minimal example: https://pastebin.com/raw/tFrRYceK. I've tested it, and it works ok.